# stack neural networks weights into 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

let us suppose we  have following neural network model :

```
model =Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',input_dim=X_train.shape[1],kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=13,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(units=num_classes,activation='softmax',kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

suppose that weight matrix inside each layer is square matrix  (for instance 13X13) and we want to put those matrix into form of (13X13X10), in other word we have in total 10 layer  and  i want to stack each matrix on each other, here is my attempt after  few research :

```
n =len(model.layers)
all_matrix =[]
for i in range(n-1):
  X =model.layers[i].get_weights()[0]
  all_matrix.append(X[None,:] )

#stack all at once
all_matrix = np.vstack(all_matrix)
```

result of this code is : (10, 13, 13) , but i want  (13,13,10), i can take all_matrix.T (transpose operation), but i think we get different matrix, so  how can i fix it?

Updated:thank you sir @Mert, what i have meant is that :

```
n =len(model.layers)-1
all_matrix =np.zeros((model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape[0],model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape[0],n))
#all_matrix =[]
for i in range(n-1):
  X =model.layers[i].get_weights()[0]
  all_matrix[:,:,i] =X
```

result : print(all_matrix.shape)

```
(13, 13, 10)
```

Comment: I think you should explain why you wanna do that too. Also, as far as I can see, you already got what you want. (10, 13, 13) already means that "You have 10 of 13x13 matrices". However, (13, 13, 10) means "You have 13 of 13x10 matrices." and this is not what you want, right?

Comment: i want to have  10  matrix of size 13 by 13 , so 10 should be in front or last one?

Comment: In front. Think of in terms of batches. If you have 64 items in a batch, you will give your model a tensor of size (64, X, Y), not the other way around. Here is another example from Keras: (64, 512, 512, 3) ---> 64 different images of 512 pixels each (with 3 channel, e.g. RGB). However, in Pytorch, the channel comes first: (64, 3, 512, 512). You can see that the item count always comes first.

Comment: look sir  about my    updated code